# NSPopover changes origin when changing height

Tags: swift, macos, menubar, nspopover

I'm trying to resize my popover by increasing/decreasing its content size programmatically

```
popover.contentSize.height += 10
```

and it's ok when macOS menubar is shown.

[image: correct]

But when menubar is hidden popover changes its resizing behavior. It jumps to left bottom corner.

[image: wrong]

I guess it's something with popover's parent window. 
How can I fix it? Or is there an another way to resize popover?

Comment: I struggled with this issue for a while, eventually I decided the best option was to detach the popover when the menubar disappears. It can look a bit weird and it won't be appropriate for every app, but in my case it was the only option. There are worse problems with popovers and the menu bar hiding; try opening an image or document in preview and making it fullscreen. You will see that a large portion of the popover is hidden when the menubar hides.